# Error (python) when deploying to new app with cloud code on windows

Tags: parse-platform

I just set up a new app on the cloud code command line, however am getting a python error when trying to deploy:

```
    $ parse deploy "Development"
Uploading source files
Finished uploading files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\local\bin\parse\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\local\bin\parse\main.py", line 369, in main
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\local\bin\parse\main.py", line 153, in handle_deploy
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\local\bin\parse\parse.py", line 139, in deploy
  File "c:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "c:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

What is going wrong?

I've also tried setting up a new cloudcode project on my system just pointing to this 'Development' app, but get the same python errors.

I have deployed to a different app on the same account successfuly before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incidentally, this problem was occurring when the Parse.com API was on a go-slow - my queries were running between 2s - 30s each.

About 30 mins later parse queries returned to normal speed (500ms - 900ms) and this Cloud Code problem resolved itself.

Perhaps it was a time-out issue for Python / cloudcode.

Comment: FYI, Parse now has an official Windows version of the command line tools for Cloud Code.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I'm using 1.0.1, but I see 1.0.2 is now available.

Comment: 1.0.2 just sorts the apps that the utility lists. I'll keep the Windows app up to date if any new features are added. One benefit of the native Windows app is that you'll get updates automatically on app restart.

Comment: I know it's an old thread, but I just did a fresh install of Windows and Parse CLI and I'm running in a very similar issue.
Whenever I try to develop or deploy an app I get [this error](https://gist.github.com/gfpacheco/883edc82bcdc851d1f89)